# mysql INNER JOIN but also NULL when not exist

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

Ok,

I'm trying to get this done the whole day but my knowledge in MySQL seems too limited.

I've got following tables:

```
time_entries
|id|comment|ticket_id|
| 1|foo    |        1|
| 2|bar    |        1|
| 3|baz    |        2|
| 4|lorem  |        3|
| 5|ipsum  |        4|

ticket
|id|name   |
| 1|ticket1|
| 2|ticket2|
| 3|ticket3|
| 4|ticket4|


custom_fields
|id|name   |
| 1|custom1|
| 2|custom2|
| 3|custom3|

custom_values
|id|custom_field_id|ticket_id|value|
| 1|              1|        1|   22|
| 2|              2|        1|   33|
| 3|              3|        1|   44|
| 4|              1|        2|   55|
| 5|              3|        2|   66|
| 6|              2|        3|   77|
| 7|              1|        4|   88|
```

What I'm trying to get is one line for each time_entry with the ticket information and the custom values. If no custom value is set for this ticket, the value in the result select must be empty or null:

```
select
|time_entries_comment|ticket_name|custom1_value|custom2_value|custom3_value|
|                 foo|    ticket1|           22|           33|           44|
|                 bar|    ticket1|           22|           33|           44|
|                 baz|    ticket2|           55|         NULL|           66|
|               lorem|    ticket3|         NULL|           77|         NULL|
|               ipsum|    ticket4|           88|         NULL|         NULL|
```

What I got so far is something like:

```
select 
  te.comment,
  t.name,
  cv1.value,
  cv2.value,
  cv3.value

  from time_entries te

  LEFT JOIN ticket t ON te.ticket_id = i.id

  LEFT JOIN custom_values cv1 ON t.id = cv1.ticket_id
  LEFT JOIN custom_fields cf1 ON cv1.custom_field_id = cf1.id AND cf1.id = 1

  LEFT JOIN custom_values cv2 ON t.id = cv2.ticket_id
  LEFT JOIN custom_fields cf2 ON cv2.custom_field_id = cf2.id AND cf2.id = 2

  LEFT JOIN custom_values cv3 ON t.id = cv3.ticket_id
  LEFT JOIN custom_fields cf3 ON cv3.custom_field_id = cf3.id AND cf3.id = 3

  WHERE t.id = 1;
```

But this gives me all matches.

I tried Inner Joins, but then I get no result, if there is no custom_value for this ticket. I also tried a Outer Join with UNION Left and Right with no success.

Any suggestions what to look for? What are the keywords here?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a process call pivot. 
This is mostly done with GROUP BY and MAX functions.

```
SELECT 
   time_entries.comment AS time_entries_comment
 , ticket.name
 , MAX(CASE WHEN custom_values.custom_field_id = 1 THEN custom_values.value ELSE NULL END) AS custom1_value
 , MAX(CASE WHEN custom_values.custom_field_id = 2 THEN custom_values.value ELSE NULL END) AS custom2_value
 , MAX(CASE WHEN custom_values.custom_field_id = 3 THEN custom_values.value ELSE NULL END) AS custom3_value
FROM 
 time_entries

INNER JOIN 
 ticket
ON
  time_entries.ticket_id = ticket.id

INNER JOIN
 custom_values  
ON
  time_entries.ticket_id = custom_values.ticket_id 

GROUP BY
    time_entries.comment
  , ticket.name

ORDER BY
  time_entries.id ASC
```

**Result**

```
time_entries_comment  name     custom1_value  custom2_value  custom3_value  
--------------------  -------  -------------  -------------  ---------------
foo                   ticket1             22             33               44
bar                   ticket1             22             33               44
baz                   ticket2             55         (NULL)               66
lorem                 ticket3         (NULL)             77           (NULL)
ipsum                 ticket4             88         (NULL)           (NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond, that was exactly what I needed! Tonight I drink a beer to you! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think the LEFT JOIN is the way to go because it allows you to get NULL values.  You simply need to add a GROUP BY statement at the end

```
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: no then I get something like only the first result of all matches

Comment: I don't think your output got pasted